# Rent a car for a day and leave it in another city in Italy

Tags: driving, italy, car-rentals, rental, naples

I want to rent a car in Italy, is it possible to take it in one city and leave it in another one? In this case, from Bari to Naples.

Also, is there a minimum number of days for a rental? Probably one day is enough in my case but 2 days should also be fine.

Comment: Hi Leo, have you done any research on this? The big international rental agencies will quote you the cost for a one way rental on their website.

Comment: I would recommend [travelling by bus](https://global.flixbus.com/bus-routes/bus-bari-naples?departureCity=3048&arrivalCity=5408&wt_mc=acq.com.FlixBus.sea-nonbrand.google.3263235012.2041619997_70534885605.ad&wt_cc1=non-branded&wt_cc5=bari%20to%20naples&gclid=Cj0KCQjwrfvsBRD7ARIsAKuDvMOHzOVoT_-NFtuH0GeBhoPep9i9Z_N1Z9UB1UXNJz7p9dX5F2VjAewaAuWiEALw_wcB) as it's cheap and no extra fees from rental agencies.

Comment: This is not a price shopping question.

Answer (score 9):

yes it's possible, many rental companies offer such a service.

If you perform a search on [autoeurope.it](https://www.autoeurope.it) (a rental car broker service which I usually use) you will find plenty of options and companies.

Keep in mind that picking the car in one location and giving it back in a different one is usually more expensive than using the same location.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a link that leads to the screenshot?

Comment: @JorenVandamme I added the website, there's no link to the search result

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can rent in one place and return to the company in an other.
This of course only works with a company with locations in both places which is willing to accept it. Depending on the company they may charge extra for the different location.

Car rentals start from half a day, or even shorter, or a single day, again depending on the company. One thing to look out for with short rentals is whether they charge milage, a fee for distances more than they would expect the car to be used.

Word of warning, driving in Italy might be rather different from driving at home, if you are not used to the Italian driving style, public transport might be the better option. Trains and buses are plentiful and not expensive.

Comment: what makes you suppose that italian driving style is so worse than his home-country driving style? I drove all over europe and I didn't notice much difference between the countries..

Comment: @Val Driving in Paris and Italy is far more aggressive and crazy than here in Portugal. It depends on whether your country is more calm or not to notice the difference...